# meteor update collection with multi option fails

Tags: mongodb, meteor, updates

Why does the `getcounter` function get called only once ?

```
collect.update({sys_RowId: {$exists : false}},
  {$set: {sys_RowId: getcounter()}},{multi: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your `getcounter` function is evaluated first. The JSON object passed to `collect.update` only contains its return value. It's not possible to pass `getcounter` as a callback to the update method.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do this in a `forEach()` loop instead:

```
collect.find(({sys_RowId: {$exists : false}}).forEach(function(doc){
  collect.update(doc._id, {$set: {sys_RowId: getcounter()}});  
});
```